# Python: finding the indices of a list that match the given sublist

Tags: python, list, indexing

Suppose there are two Python Lists:

```
my_list = ['a', 'bb', 'c', 'bb', 'cc', 'bbc']
sublist = ['bb', 'bb', 'bbc']
```

Apparently, *sublist* consists of the 1st, 3rd, and 5th elements of *my_list*. Now I want to get 
the indices `[1, 3, 5]`, given these two lists. Is there any simple way to do this?

Note that:

1. The list CAN have same elements.
2. The sublist maintains the order of the elements in the original list.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Blender is this the new workaround for "what have you tried"?

Comment: @jamylak: This seems like a homework-like problem, so I felt like asking.

Comment: I changed the name to `my_list` so you don't shadow the builtin python list

Comment: Consider `list=aXaZaXaYaZ` and `sublist=XYZ` - what should it return?

Comment: @thg435 In my application scenario (which is simplified in the above description), the case you mentioned won't happen. But thank you for mentioning this problem, which is more interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator:

```
def indices(lst, items):
    last_index = 0

    for item in items:
        last_index += lst.index(item, last_index + 1) + 1

        yield last_index
```

Answer (score 2):

@Blender's approach is great for lists (which is all this problem entails), this method is more generalized for all iterables

```
>>> def indices(a, b): # find indices of items from b inside a
        enumerate_a = enumerate(a)
        for x in b:
            for i, y in enumerate_a:
                if x == y:
                    yield i
                    break


>>> list(indices(['a', 'bb', 'c', 'bb', 'cc', 'bbc'], ['bb', 'bb', 'bbc']))
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: What's with defining `enumerate_a = enumerate(a)`?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen So when it `break`s it resumes at the next item instead of restarting from the start. This works since `enumerate` returns an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_indices(lst, sublist):
    result = []
    i = 0
    for x in sublist:
        result.append(lst.index(x, i))
        i = result[-1] + 1
    return result
```

Examples:

```
>>> get_indices(['a', 'bb', 'c', 'bb', 'cc', 'bbc'], ['bb', 'bb', 'bbc'])
[1, 3, 5]
>>> get_indices(['a', 'bb', 'c', 'bb', 'cc', 'bbc'], ['c', 'bb', 'bbc'])
[2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
def getIndex(list, sublist):
    index = []
    j = 0;
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if(sublist[j] == list[i]):
            index.append(i)
            j += 1

    return index
```

It works like ?

```
$ python -i p.py 
>>> getIndex(['bb', 'aa', 'bb'], ['aa', 'bb'])
[1, 2]
>>> getIndex(['a', 'bb', 'c', 'bb', 'cc', 'bbc'], ['bb', 'bb', 'bbc'])
[1, 3, 5]
>>> getIndex(['a', 'bb', 'c','bbc', 'bb', 'cc', 'bbc'], ['bb', 'bb', 'bbc'])
[1, 4, 6]
```

<sub>Please some one let me know if I am still wrong.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I like **Blender** 's answer most. but i don't think index() function has a parameter 'start' so I modified a little at the below.

```
idx = 0
start = 0
for i in sublist:
    idx = my_list[start:].index(i) + start
    start = idx + 1
    yield idx
```

Comment: It was similar to yours to begin with and **yes** the start paramater is not imaginary. Try it for yourself

Comment: Actually you were correct on one note, `start` isn't a keyword argument, but it is definitely a parameter, I've fixed it now on Blender's answer